# How to remove Godaddy title in Google search

Tags: blogger, google-search, html-title

I have purchased a new domain from Godaddy and connected it to my Blogger.

The problem is when I search on Google I get my blogger title like this:

> [image: This web page is parked FREE, courtesy of Godaddy.com]

However I checked the title tag on the Blogger code and every thing looks OK!

Answer (score 0):

Submit Your Site To google webmaster.. if you already done that.. then submit a sitemap.. and check your meta tags.. that they are correct.. and then use the fetch as google to fetch your homepages..

Comment: and wait for sometime... minimum 24 hrs.. maximum 72 hrs.. it will take changes..